# Drools: Time continuous drools rules not working

Tags: scala, testing, drools, kie

I'm trying to test the following drools rules:

```
declare Message
    @role(event)
    @timestamp(timestamp)
    @expires(10s)
end 

rule "throttle state activated"
when
    $meta: CurrentState(throttleState == false)
    $lastMessage: Message($lastTimestamp: timestamp)
    not (Message(timestamp > $lastMessage.timestamp))
    $messages: ArrayList(size > 20) from collect(
        $message: Message() over window:time(10s)
    )
then
    $meta.setLastThrottled($lastMessage.getTimestamp());
    $meta.setThrottleState(true);
    update($meta);
end

rule "throttle state deactivated"
when
    $meta: CurrentState(throttleState == true)
    $lastMessage: Message($lastTimestamp: timestamp)
    not (Message(timestamp > $lastMessage.timestamp))
    $messages: ArrayList(size <= 20) from collect(
        $message: Message() over window:time(10s)
    )
then
    $meta.setThrottleState(false);
    update($meta);
end
```

With the following two tests, these are in Scala and are using must matchers:

```scala
"rules" must {
  "successfully trigger (activate)" in {
    reset() // Resets the kie session and event listener
    // The insertAndFire function first advances the pseudo clock, then inserts the message, then triggers all 
    // drools rules
    (1 to 50).foreach(i => insertAndFire(mockMessage(offsetMSec = 200 * i), timeAdvanceMSec = 200))
    // The sListener simply counts every drools rule fire amount
    sListener.getCount("throttle state activated") mustBe 1 // THIS TEST SUCCEEDS
  }

  "successfully trigger (deactivate)" in {
    reset()
    (1 to 50).foreach(i => insertAndFire(mockMessage(offsetMSec = 200 * i), timeAdvanceMSec = 200))
    (1 to 60).foreach(i => {
      // Now for the next 60 seconds, we advance the clock and fire all rules to force the deactivation to not have 20 messages in the last 10 seconds.
      // This should theoretically already trigger the rule after 10 forloop iterations.
      clock.advanceTime(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
      kieSession.fireAllRules
    })
    sListener.getCount("throttle state activated") mustBe 1 // THIS TEST SUCCEEDS
    sListener.getCount("throttle state deactivated") mustBe 1 // !!! THIS TEST FAILS !!!
  }
}
```

I've tried everything, and have already debugged that the `throttleState` variable in the `CurrentState` actually turns to true, but for some reason it does not want to actually trigger the deactivation rule.

When using these rules in live code, not testing code, it works fine, so I don't understand why the rules do not properly trigger. I'm using a `PseudoSessionClock` to simulate time during these tests and this works fine for every single other rule. My suspicion is that it has to do with the collect in the deactivation rule, but I cannot pinpoint it.

I've also tried forcefully waiting 10 seconds using a timer in real life, which of course hogs the test, but this also fails. It would not be logical that this solution would work as the activation rule does properly trigger, but it was worth a try.

MCVE Project: https://github.com/ThijmenL98/DroolsMCVE

Comment: You haven't provided reproduction. If I replace the content of file `DroolDummy.drl` in your previous project https://github.com/ThijmenL98/DroolsMCVE with current rules then `sbt run` throws https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/99f0153a56405bb8b92dd57c0a7f40d8 What is your current `build.sbt`? Regarding tests, what are the imports and what specs/tests does the test class extend?

Comment: Ah that's because I probably didn't include the CurrentMessage object, I have pushed a reproducible example project to the MCVE main.

Comment: Now `sbt run` throws https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/7142f56f6b3daa75dc2b575589bb169e Should a logger be specified somewhere?

Comment: Apologies, somehow my Main did not properly get pushed to the repo. I've pushed an update but you can also just remove the `setGlobal("logger"...` line in the Main file.
That aside, there's no need to execute `sbt run`, as the tests are the problem, so `sbt test` should do it.

Comment: *"When using these rules in live code, not testing code, it works fine"* What do you mean exactly by "working fine"? What specific code not in tests produces what result while in tests it produces a different result? In tests I can see that `sListener.getCount("throttle state deactivated")` is 0 while you want it to be 1.

Comment: Correct, but when using "live code", and sending 20 messages within 10 seconds, it will activate the throttle state. Then, when only sending a single second in the next 30 seconds, it will properly deactivate the throttle state. I try to simulate this behaviour in the second test, yet it does not actually deactivate.

Comment: Just trying to figure out. I moved test code to main and `sListener.getCount("throttle state deactivated")` produces 0 instead of 1 as in tests https://github.com/ThijmenL98/DroolsMCVE/compare/main...DmytroMitin:DroolsMCVE:main So what did you mean by "When using these rules in live code, not testing code, it works fine"? The code seems to work similarly (maybe incorrectly or in unexpected way but similarly) both in tests and not tests.

Comment: For me it works when running it as `sbt run` using fake messages to trigger the rules, i can't really explain it in any other way. I just send 20 messages it triggers the activation rule. Then i wait for a while (>10s) and `fireAllRules()` to trigger rule re-evaluation, which triggers the disable rule.

In detail, I run two tasks in parallel, one which submits messages, and one which fires all rules every second. Once the submit task is done with sending, eventually the disable rule will trigger as it has received <20 messages collectively in the last 10 seconds.